# css hover border without letter-spacing

Tags: css

CSS:

```
.item {
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 25px;
letter-spacing: 0.65em;
padding-left: -0.65em;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0 50px -1px 0;
font-style: normal;
border-bottom: 1px solid #D7D3CE;
}

.item:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

is there any solution to cut the border on hover only till the end of the last letter (without the letter-spacing)?

[image]

thanks for any tipps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not looking for a transition, you can rely on gradient to create the border. Reduce its width by the amount of `letter-spacing` and it should be good

```css
.item {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.65em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 50px -1px 0;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(var(--c,#D7D3CE) 0 0) no-repeat
   0 100%/calc(100% - .65em) 1px; /* width = (100% - .65em)  height = 1px*/
}

.item:hover {
  --c: #000000; /* update the color on hover */
}
```

```html
<span class="item">focus</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of `clip-path` looks like a rather elegant solution:

```css
.item {
  --ls: 0.65em;
  letter-spacing: var(--ls);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D7D3CE;
  transition: border-bottom-color .4s;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, calc(100% - var(--ls)) 0%, calc(100% - var(--ls)) 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.item:hover {
  border-bottom-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<span class="item">focus</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.65em;
  padding-left: -0.65em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 50px -1px 0;
  font-style: normal;
}

.item:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  width: calc(100% - 0.65em);
  background-color: #D7D3CE;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.item:hover:after {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<span class="item">Focus</span>
```